# How to integrate TM1 server or TM1 rest API to R

Tags: r, cognos-tm1

I have recently working on cognos TM1 which is a planning,budgeting and forecasting tool. But limited with statistical calculations. To add on to its capability I want to integrate it to R. 
Can anyone give some head-outs about it?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found until now, is using R with python.

There is a library called TM1py, which you can query data from tm1 to python.

Then you can you PythonInR package to send this information to R.

There is a way to do this direcly using httr package from R, but until now, I couldn't do it.